# When creating custom collections via rest API ,it says collection unavailable on google ? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: shopify

When creating custom collections using rest API ,The collection appears to show unavailable on google ,How to fix this ? so that it appears on Google.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is not a problem of the products and not of the collection?

Comment: @FabioFilippi I want the collection to appear on google i use a backend api call to show products on this collection ,so i dont manually add products to this collection.I just want them while creating to be available on google

Answer (score 0):

Google is a Sales Channel in your store? Therefore it is up to you to tick off the box to make that collection available to Google the Sales Channel. That is the first thing you should do anyway. Go to your Admin and turn your collection on to that Sales Channel.

If you do not have access to the Admin, you will have to ask the merchant to do that for you as there are no API calls that allow you to do this, as far as I know, it may remain the domain of Plus stores only. You can check that further.

Comment: How can i add a collection to the sales channel ?

Comment: You need to look into it. It is complicated. https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/interfaces/Publishable